# What are the different ways of switching 110 VAC power?

Tags: power

I am working on a project where I need to break the path providing 110V to a motor.

What are different ways of doing it? I am aware of only two ways:

1. Using a mechanical switch,
2. A relay.

Are there any other safe, reliable and possibly cheaper ways of doing this? Maybe a solid state solution?

Comment: Motors are highly inductive, when you "break" the path, there will be a HUGE spike in voltage. The voltage spike will be proportional to the current that the motor draws. Depending on your voltage spike you can possibly also use a BJT, IGBT, or 2 FETs. FETs will give off least amount of heat. So two questions: 1. Is it single-phase AC motor? 2. At what VA are running the motor?

Comment: You may have already answered your own question (hint: google "solid state relay")

Comment: Triacs and SCRs come to mind

Comment: Can you clarify: Do you mean break as in "stop the motor" or as in "electrically isolate the motor to make it safe to work on" - I believe only a mechanical isolation/disconnection would be considered acceptable for the 2nd scenario, I certainly would not be touching any wires which are only "off" under solid-state control as there can be leakage etc.

Comment: What current/power rating are we talking about?

Comment: Assuming the project is controlled by a computer, and that computer is connected to the internet, have it send a text message to your assistant, telling him/her to go unplug the motor.  :-)

Comment: Well you can use a relay to connect a resistor to the motor when turning it off. That way it can dissipate the energy being kept in the rotating mass. That is if the motor is not too big. You have more expensive relays that can do it with higher loads.